# Is it possible to test touch gestures with a "non-touchable" laptop?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, touch, windows-phone, gesture

While developing Windows Store apps and WP8 apps, is it possible to test the "touch" gestures while using a laptop that doesn't support touch? Are there parallel mouse or keyboard actions/combinations that will do the same thing as a "pinch" or a "flick" gesture (to imitate semantic zoom and unzoom) for example?

Comment: I'd recommend some testing framework for touch/tap action simulation. Selenium has some, but these actions are not yet available for C#... :(

Comment: You can test some touch gestures in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the simulator, there are buttons at the right that let you simulate multi-touch. It's not convenient, but it mostly works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441475(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to use the WP8 SDK yet but if the SDK is like WP7 (from what I hear from others it is) use the simulator that comes with the SDK and use Multitouch Vista to emulate the touches with this [Guide to using Multitouch Vista](http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7). You will just need any other USB mouse (note though using the built-in trackpad as another mouse has been hit and miss in my experience with Multitouch Vista)

For Windows Store Apps the easiest way to simlute gestures only us by using the [provided simulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/30/microsoft-windows-simulator-touch-emulation.aspx). You can still use Multitouch Vista but the dots to track the points won't show in the Metro Environment.